# How to Retrieve an Oracle Sequence value?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, sequence, odp.net

I need to retrieve a VarChar sequence value. How is that done using C# and Oracle's ODP components?

A less-specific answer might help, too (e.g., how it's done in VB or how it's done using a different component set).

Comment: There is no "varchar sequence" in Oracle

Comment: Yes, there is - we use them at work (as Bob Jarvis mentions below). They may not be "the preferred method," I don't know, but we do use them.

Comment: Please show us the CREATE SEQUENCE statement for that "varchar" sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get back a string value representing a sequence value you'll need to convert the sequence's NEXTVAL to a character string using TO_CHAR; something like

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(MY_SCHEMA.MY_SEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, 'TM9') FROM DUAL
```

Don't know C# well enough to advise on that, but you can probably work it out from there.

Share and enjoy.